# Instagram API returns 400 bad request c#

Tags: c#, instagram, http-status-code-400

I am using instagram API in my web application.

1. Get code - success
2. Get access token - success
3. make user follow my page(action=follow) - error (400 bad request)

If i post on the same url from my local machine or any other IP it works.

On step 3 it returned me error "Client limit reached". It seems that instagram has blocked my IP. I was just test it alone and i hardly made 200 to 300 requests during last 3 hours.

How can i get rid of this or where can i contact instagram about this ?

Comment: Hello, have you got any solution for this issue?